# Procedural Node Setup tied to Camera's View?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I want to color surfaces which are able to be seen from a viewpoint.　So I made nodes like this.

[image]

But the setup doesn't entirely work as expected. From the top, it does what I intended...

[image]

...but from the bottom, it does not show what I expected.

[image]

I rotated the spherical object 180° along X-axis and I expected both show the same result.

What is wrong with my node setup?

Comment: If you want a view based shader should you be using *View Vector* from a *Camera Data* node as input instead?

Comment: Yes, I want the vector from a Camera.